# How should i define the typescript type of a controller in a node/express app

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, try-catch

I wrote a try-catch wrapper for all my controllers:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

export const trycatch =
  (controller: any) => async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      await controller(req, res);
    } catch (error: unknown) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
```

But i am confused as to "How should i define the type of the controller". Notice there i have used the type "any" but i don't really wanna use it. This try-catch wrapper may be used for different controllers like:

```
export const RandomController = trycatch(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { username } = req.params;
  res.status(200).json({ message: `Random Message` });
});
```